# Closing all possible GUI related elements

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to close (or get a handle to) all possible windows, dialogs, prompts, etc. created with Java?

I have an app that creates GUI elements here and there (while it automatically runs tests and such) and sometimes it leaves these elements open. I would like to be able to close all those things from one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit. I am teh retarded xP

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows%28%29

This will give you every `Window` (parentclass of `Frame`, `Dialog`, `JWindow`,  Grandparent of `JFrame`, `JDialog`, etc).

---

Original

Well [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getFrames%28%29) gets all of the `Frame`s that are open. I don't think there is an equivalent for `Dialog`, but there is the `getOwnedWindows()` method on `Window`. I don't know who owns dialogs constructed with a `null` `Frame` argument.

Comment: Well, i didn't test it all that exhaustively, but "Works on my machine" and that's all i care :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set a collection and then make it close each element.

EDIT:

Ok, here is an exemple, I don't know if ArrayList is the best choice here :

```
class Main{
    public static final ArrayList<Window> containers = new ArrayList<Window>();

    public static final void closeEverything(){
        ListIterator<Window> list = containers.getListIterator();
        while(list.hasNext()){
              list.next().dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you create a Window that you wish to be disposable, you just have to add :

Main.containers.add(this);

in the constructor.

Comment: This assumes you register all windows yourself? Which means that all created dialogs also need to be registered in user code?

Comment: This assumes that you extends your the extended Window class you use (Frame, etc...) to add Main.containers.add(this); in the constructor. Is this a bad idea ?

Comment: Yeah, the point is that i don't register the windows myself. I could go through all the code created (not by me) but that would be way, way too much of a bother. 

@Williwaw Cirse
Sounds like a bad idea to me. 

ps. (I know this is the wrong place to ask, but) how do you do a carriage return in the comments?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible, I've never seen any.